# First connect with NSURLConnection in iOS 9 on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, ios9

I using XCode 7.

For iOS 9 I add in `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

In app I have login button. When user press login button I try load some data from Internet

```
 NSData *respPayload = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:endpointUrl];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
 [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
 [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
 [request setHTTPBody:data];   
  respPayload = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
```

I get error

> kCFURLErrorTimedOut  = -1001

If user press once again login button this code work perfect. Problem is when first time I try to load data I get error, only for first time. It's sounds strange. In iOS 8 I don't have this problem. For Simulator I don't have this problem, only for device in iOS 9. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything.

For my problem helps add to `info.plist` my domain:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YOUR_URL.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendAsynchronousRequest` was deprecated in iOS 9

Use `NSURLSession` instead like below

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // The server answers with an error because it doesn't receive the params
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```